# Construct and print name lists with macros

Tags: macros

I have to print author lists in different places. In the cover the author should be printed as

```
Name1 \\
Name2 \\
Name3
```

But in other places it should be printed inline.

```
Name1, Name2 and Name3
```

I have a macro that construct the first requirement

%%% Multiple author command

```
\newcommand{\listof@authors}{}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\mainauthor}[1]{%
  \ifdefempty{\listof@authors}{%
      \gappto\listof@authors{#1}
    }{%
      \gappto\listof@authors{\\#1}
    }
}
```

But now, I think I need to store the names in a array like object and create two different macros to print the names. Which package can I use?
(note: I need to be able to detect the last element of the list to add `and` instead of the `,`).

Comment: Are you open to `expl3` syntax?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am open to expl3, but sometimes my brain is not to understand it ;)

Comment: If you need further explanations --> please ask then -- `expl3` is quite new to me to, but it's easy to understand it after some first trials.

Comment: @ChrisianHupfer Thanks, your explanation is fine. It is just me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such lists can very easily defined with `expl3` and its `clist` or `seq` facilities. Here, I show `seq` as an example:

First define a global variable, say, `\g_textnik_listofauthors_seq`

Each author is added to list by `\seq_put_right:Nn`

`\printauthorstacked` shows the list (well, sequence) with `\seq_use:Nn` and `\printauthorinline` does this inline, with individual separators. The first separator is `,` for two elements, the second is for more than two elements and the last one is meant for the last two elements, which should be an 'and' according to the O.P.

If the last item has to be accessed in another context, use the `\seq_get_right:NN` macro from `expl3`, in an appropiate wrapper command.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\RequirePackage{etoolbox}




\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_textnik_listofauthors_seq

\newcommand{\mainauthor}[1]{%
  \seq_put_right:Nn \g_textnik_listofauthors_seq {#1}
}

\newcommand{\printauthorstacked}{%
  \seq_use:Nn \g_textnik_listofauthors_seq {\par}
}

\newcommand{\printauthorinline}{%
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_textnik_listofauthors_seq {,\ } {,\ } {\  and\ }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mainauthor{Groucho}
\mainauthor{Zeppo}
\mainauthor{Harpo}
\mainauthor{Gummo}
\mainauthor{Chico}

\printauthorstacked

\printauthorinline\ wrote this paper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Such list can be very easily defined by TeX primitives:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\readauthors#1{\def\authorsL{}\readauthorsA#1,,}
\def\readauthorsA#1,{\ifx,#1,\else\addto\authorsL{\data{#1}}%
   \expandafter\readauthorsA\fi}
\def\printstacked{\par\def\data##1{\hbox{##1}}\authorsL}
\def\printinline{\def\data##1{##1%
      \def\data####1####2{\ifx####2\relax\space and ####1\else , ####1\fi####2}}%
   \authorsL\relax
}

\readauthors{First,Second,Third}

\printstacked
Test: \printinline

\bye
```

The list is stored in the form `\data{First}\data{Second}...` and all what you need is to define the right meaning of the `\data` macro.